# Как правильно создать запрос к базе данных в SQL

Tags: база-данных, sql

Предположим, есть (вторая) таблица

```
PurchasingByMonth
Month   Name
    6   Иван
    4   Сергей
    12  Мария
    1   Ольга
    3   Кирилл
    8   Михаил
    1   Иван
    5   Сергей
    4   Иван
```

вопрос - в каком квартале года было больше всего покупателей, сколько их было

Comment: Чем-то напомнили солдата Швейка и его головоломку про бабушку швейцара.

Comment: Разве ж это головоломка? Вот головоломка: http://sql-ex.ru/exercises.php?N=-3 
:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно компактнее:

```
select top 1 ((month - 1)/3 + 1) as q, count(1) as c
from PurchasingByMonth 
group by q
order by c desc
```

Comment: Можно и компактнее, когда знаешь, какая СУБД.
Тогда можно еще и with ties написать.

Comment: Да ладно. Не считая, `top 1` и названия столбца `month` (которое дано в условии), запрос вполне себе SQL92-валидный.

Comment: Спасибо вам, товарищи ;) помогли.. )

Comment: @Nofate 
Мне все равно, если клиент доволен. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) as qty, 
case when Month between 1 and 3 then 'i'  
when Month between 4 and 6 then 'ii'
when Month between 7 and 9 then 'iii'
when Month between 10 and 12 then 'iv'
end quarter   
from PurchasingByMonth 
group by case when Month between 1 and 3 then 'i'  
when Month between 4 and 6 then 'ii'
when Month between 7 and 9 then 'iii'
when Month between 10 and 12 then 'iv'
end 
having count(*) >= ALL(select count(*) from PurchasingByMonth 
group by case when Month between 1 and 3 then 'i'  
when Month between 4 and 6 then 'ii'
when Month between 7 and 9 then 'iii'
when Month between 10 and 12 then 'iv'
end)
```